# "Invalid signature"...."you need to load kernal first" error....when trying to access Advanced options in Recovery Mode Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, recovery-mode

This is as far as I get when trying to get into the Recovery Mode to rest my password since Ubuntu 18.04 does not recognize the correct password. At the top of the screen it says :

> GNU GRUB Ver 2.04

With six options listed I scroll to the second and choose:

> Ubuntu,with Linux 4.15.0-154-generic (Recovery mode)<

```
Then it tries to load:
```

> Loading Linux 4.15.0-154-generic<

and it gives this error message:

> error: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-154-generic has invalid signature.
> Loading initial ram disk...
> error: You need to load the kernal first.
> Press any key to continue.

Also in general before I had this password issue, after powering up the computer, Ubuntu would go through a litany of steps it was checking scrolling though pages and pages of things it was doing before I would get the Ubuntu sign on screen.

Can someone please help? (I'm using anther computer now obviously to post this issue about the other one). Thanks in advance.